# How to change redact color

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm using `itext 7.1.8` and I need to change the redact color but when I'm trying to do it the color doesn't change.
My code looks like the following:

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(pdfDoc));
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream("ResultFile.pdf"));
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer);
final PdfPage page = doc.getFirstPage();
final float[] borderColorBlack = { 0, 0, 0 };

PdfAnnotation redact = new PdfRedactAnnotation(new Rectangle(1, 1, 37, 20))
    .setTitle(new PdfString(""))
    .setColor(new float[] {0, 0, 0})
    .setFlag(PdfAnnotation.TOGGLE_NO_VIEW)
    .put(PdfName.Subj, PdfName.Redact)
    .put(PdfName.OC, new PdfArray(borderColorBlack));

page.addAnnotation(redact);
PdfCleanUpTool cleaner = new PdfCleanUpTool(doc, true);
cleaner.cleanUp();
doc.close();
```

How can I change the redact color area?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this issue [here](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/faq/how-to-create-and-apply-redactions). I just have added flag:

```java
PdfAnnotation redact = new PdfRedactAnnotation(new Rectangle(1, 1, 37, 20))
    .setTitle(new PdfString(""))
    .setColor(new float[] {0, 0, 0})
    .setFlag(PdfAnnotation.TOGGLE_NO_VIEW)
    .put(PdfName.Subj, PdfName.Redact)
    .put(PdfName.IC, new PdfArray(borderColorBlack))   // Added code here
    .put(PdfName.OC, new PdfArray(borderColorBlack));
```